# Block until a DOM event occurs with core.async

Tags: clojurescript, core.async

I've got a Clojurescript project where i need to block the whole thread execution until an DOM event occurs.

In this case, the event is [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), which fire when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed. But it could be extended to any DOM (or non-DOM) event.

As i'm new to Clojurescript and async i wasn't sure how to solve this problem. My first guess was to use the core.async library. After some doc scraping, i came with that function:

```
(defn wait-dom-loading
  []
  (let [c (async/chan)]
 {1} (.addEventListener js/document "DOMContentLoaded" (fn [] (async/go (async/>! c true))))
 {2} (async/go (async/<! c))))
```

The way i understand it is that {2} *takes* from **chan c** and is parked until the listener in {1} evaluates the function and *puts* a value in **chan c**.

As i barely understand how to do unit tests on asynchronous code (beside puting it in an (async done) expression and calling done when done) i can't verify if what i did is correct. I tried this snippet:

```
(do
  (wait-dom-loading)
  (-> (dommy/sel1 :p)
      (dommy/set-text! "Loaded !")))
```

With a **p** block inside an html page, and noticed that the console complains about the js code trying to manipulate a DOM object that don't yet exists. That confirms that what i did didn't work as planned.

1. What does seems wrong in this example ?
2. Is this overkill ? Could i solve that with a smaller solution or even **gasp** a built-in funtion ?
3. Is putting my script at the bottom of my html page a not so bad practice ?

As this was my first question on stack overflow, i hope it is well-written enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would do it:

```
(ns domevent.core
    (:require [cljs.core.async :as async :refer [chan]])
    (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]]))

(enable-console-print!)    
(def ch (chan))

(go
    (pr "i am waiting")
    (pr (<! ch))
    (dommy/set-text! (dommy/sel1 :p) "Loaded !"))

(.addEventListener js/document "DOMContentLoaded" (fn [] (go (>! ch "hello"))))
```

Or more simply:

```
(let [ch (chan)]
    (go
        (pr "i am waiting")
        (<! ch)
        (dommy/set-text! (dommy/sel1 :p) "Loaded !"))

    (.addEventListener js/document "DOMContentLoaded" #(close! ch)))
)
```

The point here is the ch, which is shared by reader and writer. When `(<! ch)` happens, there is nothing in ch yet, so this thread is parked (i.e. stops and waits for anything to appear in ch). Meanwhile, the DOMContentLoaded occurs, and the handler writes to the channel. Then the former thread continues.

Comment: Thanks. I think we should edit your answer to be more explicit, i took some time to realize that what i wanted was in it. Also to be .addEventListener seems to be the first expression to be evaluated.
Dommy is actually irrelevant here, i think i'll remove it from my question.

As i don't have a high due to my recent account, i can't make the edit effective but maybe someone can review/accept it ?

Comment: Nevermind, ignore my comment on the position of .addEventListener. :)